# unique_ptr usage - map of class

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me with the code below to display the contents of the class object?

Q1 - can anyone confirm - if this is the correct way to store the pointer to table class object in the map?

Q 2 - How to output the contents on the entire record in the map?

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Table
{
    public:
    int c1, c2, c3;
    Table() {}

    Table(int _c1,int _c2,int _c3)
    {
      c1=_c1;
      c2=_c2;
      c3=_c3;
    }
};

int main()
{

   std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Table>> mapTable;
   std::unique_ptr<Table> up(new Table(1,2,3));

   // Is this correct way to store the pointer?
   mapTable.insert(std::make_pair(0,std::move(up)));

   // How can I display c1,c2,c3 values here with this iterator?
   for (const auto &i : mapTable)
    std::cout << i.first << " " << std::endl;

   return 0;
}

// How to get the output in the form - 0,1,2,3 ( 0 map key, 1,2,3 are c1,c2,c3 )
// std::cout << i.first << " " << i.second.get() << std::endl;  --> incorrect output
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1 - can anyone confirm - if this is the correct way to store the pointer to table class object in the map?

Yes, that is the correct way of storing a `unique_ptr` in a container. Unique pointers are non-copyable, so you need to `std::move()` it when passing it to a function - and you are doing that.

> Q 2 - How to output the contents on the entire record in the map?

Unless I am missing something obvious, you actually did the hardest part of the job. Just do:

```
for (const auto &i : mapTable)
{
    std::cout << i.first << " " << std::endl;

    std::cout << i.second->c1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << i.second->c2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << i.second->c3 << std::endl;
}
```

The iterator is an iterator to a `std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<Table>>` (which is the value type of the map), so `i.first` provides access to the key, and `i.second` provides access to the mapped value (the unique pointer, in your case).